# ASP.NET 3.5 Webservices

Tags: c#, web-services

I am about to start my first web service in ASP.NET. when searching in google it shows

```
RestFul Service

SOAP services

WCF
```

Which one is stable?.What is the key differece among them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define "stable" ;-p

If you mean "time in the field", then for .NET the order would be SOAP (asmx), WCF, REST

Note that there is a big shift between the data-centric REST services (typical of ADO.NET Data Services) and WCF / asmx, which are operation-centric.

REST is perhaps more flexible for the caller; WCF / asmx has more rigid control (in terms of exposing discreet operations). Both have their places, but I *tend* to still make my default the operation-centric approach (via WCF) in most cases (a defined number of things to test, etc).

WCF is a bit more evolved than the original web-services offered in .NET, and has better WSE support (although asmx can be extended via WSE3). If you are starting today, WCF would be a better choice than asmx in most cases.

Comment: I mean which is quite worth to use.

Comment: It depends on what you want. WCF would be my default, with ADO.NET Data Services **if** you understand the data security aspects.

Comment: oh! No ,I do nott want to go for ADO.NET Data Service with Entity Framework ,as a starter it will beat my head.Just i watched some MSDN Video on Entity Framework . So My Plan is to use WCF Data Services along with LINQ to SQL.Just I am searching some articles to see wheter it is possible or not.Thank you Marc for your reply.

Answer (score 4):

Definitely go with WCF - it's the current and future technology for cross-machine communication.

The question of SOAP vs. REST is a bit like manual vs. automatic transmission - it depends on your needs and preferences.

**SOAP** is in general a bit more sturdy - it has things like WSDL and XSD - schema and metadata to clearly and definitely describe a service and all its methods and all its data being passed around. Highly useful in enterprise environments.

**REST** on the other hand is the much more approachable, easy to understand, just-point-your-code-at-a-URL-and-get-XML-back approach. Works well, it's almost human-readable, less overhead, but also less "security" - since there's really hardly any metadata describing the service - either you know it yourself since you're the author of the service, or the service provider has a good documentation somewhere.

So there's no clear winner in my opinion - pick the one closer to your needs and your preferences.